# php multiple if else statement how to combine into one function?

Tags: php, if-statement

i got 7 if else statement, may I know how i can compile it into one function file? so I just trigger the function rather a long and messy code.

below are my codes:

```
<?php
$r1a = $_POST['rowone'];
if ($r1a<7) {
    $r2a=$r1a+1;
    } else {
    $r2a=$r1a+1-7;
}
if ($r2a<7) {
    $r3a=$r2a+1;
    } else {
    $r3a=$r2a+1-7;
}
if ($r3a<7) {
    $r4a=$r3a+1;
    } else {
    $r4a=$r3a+1-7;
}
if ($r4a<7) {
    $r5a=$r4a+1;
    } else {
    $r5a=$r4a+1-7;
}
if ($r5a<7) {
    $r6a=$r5a+1;
    } else {
    $r6a=$r5a+1-7;
}
if ($r6a<7) {
    $r7a=$r6a+1;
    } else {
    $r7a=$r6a+1-7;
}
?>
```

the second problem I have is adding all together, there are 7 vertical row that have 3 value and another 5 row that have 2 value to add. I found out my code over here if there is a total value of 12 it will show 0 because of my code -12. Is there anyone I wan alter the code if the value is 12, the result will +1-12?
Thanks!

```
<?php
$r4a = $r1a+$r2a+$r3a;
if ($r4a<12) {
    $r4a=$r4a;
        } else {
    $r4a=$r4a-12;
}
$r4b = $r1b+$r2b+$r3b;
if ($r4b<12) {
    $r4b=$r4b;
        } else {
    $r4b=$r4b-12;
}
$r4c = $r1c+$r2c+$r3c;
if ($r4c<12) {
    $r4c=$r4c;
        } else {
    $r4c=$r4c-12;
}
$r4d = $r1d+$r2d+$r3d;
if ($r4d<12) {
    $r4d=$r4d;
        } else {
    $r4d=$r4d-12;
}
$r4e = $r1e+$r2e+$r3e;
if ($r4e<12) {
    $r4e=$r4e;
        } else {
    $r4e=$r4e-12;
}
$r4f = $r1f+$r2f+$r3f;
if ($r4f<12) {
    $r4f=$r4f;
       } else {
    $r4f=$r4f-12;
}
$r4g = $r1g+$r2g+$r3g;
if ($r4g<12) {
    $r4g=$r4g;
        } else {
    $r4g=$r4g-12;
}
$r4h = $r2h+$r3h;
if ($r4h<12) {
    $r4h=$r4h;
        } else {
    $r4h=$r4h-12;
}
$r4i = $r2i+$r3i;
if ($r4i<12) {
    $r4i=$r4i;
        } else {
    $r4i=$r4i-12;
}
$r4j = $r2j+$r3j;
if ($r4j<12) {
    $r4j=$r4j;
        } else {
    $r4j=$r4j-12;
}
$r4k = $r2k+$r3k;
if ($r4k<12) {
    $r4k=$r4k;
        } else {
    $r4k=$r4k-12;
}
$r4l = $r2l+$r3l;
if ($r4l<12) {
    $r4l=$r4l;
        } else {
    $r4l=$r4l-12;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't rely on register_globals being on; use the $_POST superglobal instead

Comment: Well the Excel IF tests __>= 7__ while your PHP if tests __> 7__, so the formula conversion isn't exactly correct

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $r2a, because you're not doing anything to change $r1a

Comment: It's good practice to open a new question instead of editing your old question if they're very different. Especially since the comments above about Excel now seem rather silly compared to the current state of the question.

Comment: First you could shorten each if statement by doing `$r6a = $r5a < 7 ? $r5a+1 : $r5a+1-7`

Comment: I was going to answer your question using a for loop but some explanation to what you're doing might help a lot. There's no need to create a new variable, you can reuse the old variable unless you need to keep the old values, this allows for a loop. Otherwise look into arrays, they also allow for looping.

Comment: couldnt this be done with the modulo operator instead of all those if's

Comment: You only get rowone from POST, right?

Comment: Have you heard of arrays?

Comment: @EdHeal, yes i heard of arrays, but i always make a confuse on array so thats why i make it a long steps instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the if's at all. Modulo operations should solve it for you.

```
function inc($a) {
    return ($a % 7)+1;
}

$r1a = $_POST['rowone'];
$r2a = inc($r1a);
$r3a = inc($r2a);
$r4a = inc($r3a);
$r5a = inc($r4a);
$r6a = inc($r5a);
$r7a = inc($r6a);
```

Code hasn't been tested, but you get the general idea.

Another alternative:

```
$v = $_POST['rowone'];
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
$b = array_slice($arr, 0, $v-1);
$arr = array_slice($arr, $v-1);
$arr = array_merge($arr, $b);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer to your second question where I have only made 0 into 1 and kept the rest as it were(To clearify, if the input to `mod12` e.g `$r1a+$r2a+$r3a` is a multiple of 12 it will return 1, in other cases it will return a standard `modulo 12` e.g 13 will become 1):

```
function mod12($a) {
    $m = $a % 12;
    if ($m == 0) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        return $m;
    }
}

$r4a = mod12($r1a+$r2a+$r3a);
$r4b = mod12($r1b+$r2b+$r3b);
$r4c = mod12($r1c+$r2c+$r3c);
$r4d = mod12($r1d+$r2d+$r3d);
$r4e = mod12($r1e+$r2e+$r3e);
$r4f = mod12($r1f+$r2f+$r3f);
$r4g = mod12($r1g+$r2g+$r3g);
$r4h = mod12($r2h+$r3h);
$r4i = mod12($r2i+$r3i);
$r4j = mod12($r2j+$r3j);
$r4k = mod12($r2k+$r3k);
$r4l = mod12($r2l+$r3l);
```

Comment: this function included a 0, i only need the value to be from 1 to 7.

Comment: Try it now. If `rowone` is 3, then the values becomes 3456712

Comment: hi @atomman, tested and the code works flawlessly, as i know inc represent the function name, how bout $a? and this code `($a % 7)+1` mind to explain abit so I know how it works and take this as a lesson. thanks again

Comment: `$a` is just a local variable that only exists within the scope of the function. For the line `$r2a = inc($r1a);` `$a` will contain the same value as `$r1a`. Now, `($a % 7)+1`, `%` is the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Which means that if `$a` is less then 7, it will not change. If its equal or greater then 7, it will subtract 7 until the value becomes less then 7. In mathematics the result of the modulo operation is the remainder of the Euclidean division `$a / 7`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I've added a second problem I encounter, i use your method but it didn't work, please assist.

Comment: As to your second question I need some more infomation, especially what should the value become if it starts off at 13? Should that also return 1, because if that is the case you could simply change `$r4a=$r4a-12;` to `$r4a=$r4a-11;`. If that is not the case you need to add an `elseif` statement to your existing code.

Comment: As a side note I would probably use matrix structure for a job like this. It would make the code much cleaner, and you wouldn't have to remember all those variables names.

Comment: what is matrix? and basically how to do it? maybe you got an email or messenger? I ask at there will be much more better by the way for my question i just missed out that there were a bug in my code. this basically what i want the code to work. `$r4a = $r1a+$r2a+$r3a;` if this total is lesser than 12 then it add all up, if the value is 13 then it will minus 12 and if the value is greater than 25 then it will minus 24.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you try to achieve, this should work:

```
$r1a = $_POST['rowone'];
for ( $i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ){
  $cur = 'r'.$i.'a';
  $next = 'r'.($i+1).'a';
  $$next = $$cur < 7 ? $$cur+1 : $$cur+1-7
}
```

Comment: I would rather see you put those values into an array, instead of molesting variables in that way.

Comment: Oh poor variables! :) I just tried to shorten the code, not change its effects as I dunno what happens next

Comment: Actually shorter if you use an array. `$v = $_POST['rowone'];
$arr = array($v);
for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
 array_push($arr, ($v+$i) % 7);
}`

Comment: @Jeff sorry about that, I had forgotten to double the $ sign